# adding return true to jquery cycle's next/previous buttons

Tags: jquery, xhtml, return, button, cycle

The jQuery code used:

```
$('#contentspacer').cycle({fx:'fade',speed:2500,timeout:6000,next:'.next',prev:'.prev'});
$('.pause').click(function() {$('#contentspacer').cycle('pause'); return false;});
$('.play').click(function() {$('#contentspacer').cycle('resume'); return false;});
```

The html used for the "navigation":

```
<div class="pnbtns"><a href="#" class="prev">&#8592;</a> <a href="#" class="pause">pause</a> <a href="#" class="play">play</a> <a href="#" class="next">&#8594;</a></div>
```

As you can see, the play and the pause buttons work fine and do not add the hashtag at the end, the next and the previous button still work, but add the hashtag.

What I want to do is add the return false; to the .prev and .next buttons, without using inline javascript (I know how to do it that way) and without leaving the links empty(must validate strict xhtml).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('.next, .prev').live('click', function(){
   return false;
});
```